# Facebook share button add php to url

Tags: php, facebook, href

I am trying to make it so people on my forum can Share this with their friends on facebook. I made this button with the function I found online. The only problem is that I need to add some `php` to the code because it needs to be something like this `http://#####/boards/stel-jezelf-voor/<?php $reaction['reactie']?>` but this isnt working for me.

The code I use:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://#####/boards/stel-jezelf-voor/" data-layout="button" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true">
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A//#####/boards/nieuws-events%5D" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
Delen</a></div>
```

script:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.0&appId=426507524447885&autoLogAppEvents=1';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>    

    </div>
```

**I tried this:**

```
<div id="showtopics">
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $url; ?>" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Delen</a></div>

<?php $url = $url[1]; ?>
```

This wil open a tab when I press the button but it will return a blank page

Comment: Can you please link of uploaded Files ?

Comment: What do you mean?@EngrZardari

Comment: means have you uploaded your project on live server ?

Comment: what happens if you click on the link ? the link you have made !

Comment: is <?php $reaction['id']?> is int ?

Comment: @EngrZardari its just text. And if I click the link as the code I have here above it will do the right thing en I can post the link but now I need to add `php` to the url it needs to post on Facebook

Comment: Then _show us_ how you tried to do that! _“but this isnt working for me”_ is not a proper problem description. Please go read [ask], and then edit your questipon accordingly.

Comment: @CBroe I tried the answer down below.... and look what I answered there

Comment: Yes, there you did exactly the BS you should not do (“not working”), again.

Comment: @CBroe Bro you can just look at my code and tell me what I did wrong instead of complaining about my comments.

Comment: Are you kidding me now? You have not shown us what you tried in that regard to begin with! Your code above does not contain _any_ attempt to modify the URL dynamically, or even to output `$reaction['reactie']` somewhere. So, again, _show us what you tried_ …

Comment: @CBroe I added what I have tried.

Comment: So go check the generated HTML code first of all - does that look like you did expect it to? (And what is `$url = $url[1];` supposed to achieve, _after_ you outpu the link already?)

Answer (score 0):

You can do just like that:

```html
<a target="_blank"
 href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?= urlencode($myurl) ?>">
Share</a>
```

that link will share your page on facebook in new window.
$url must be predefined url like "www.myforum.com/question?id=etc".

Comment: I tried this: `$myurl = "https://#####/boards/".$url[1]."/".$topic['url']."";` but that isnt working

Comment: Why you use dashes in url?

Comment: that's what you use in an url?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=facebook.com - go to link, it works!